# A strang flicker when I use AVPlay

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a strang  flicker when I use AVPlay：

[image]

I create a demo to show this bug：  [***Demo***](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611161931/https://github.com/ChenYilong/avplayerTest)  。

I am referring to the flicker from the beginning, that one happens because I have a transition between the image and the movie. but I need
the image showing before  the video  appear.

because I have to keep image showing,before the video is downloaded completely.

Can anyone fix this bug？

Answer (score 0):

You can make this transition smoother by using an animation when hiding the image view:

```
if (!self.imageView.hidden) {
    NSTimeInterval fadeDuration = .5;
    static CGFloat invisibleAlpha = .0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeDuration animations:^{
        self.imageView.alpha = invisibleAlpha;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.player play];
    }];
}
```

Note that you can set the .5 value to another value.

Comment: but I need
the image showing before  the video  appear.